# Как в AutoHotKey сделать выделение определенной области?

Tags: autohotkey

Как можно в программе AutoHotKey выделить мышкой определенную область? Допустим в пэйнте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью [`MouseClickDrag`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClickDrag.htm):

```
; предварительно каким-либо образом выбрать в Paint инструмент выделения прямоугольником
MouseClickDrag, left, 200, 200, 600, 600
```